# Deployment Module on Drupal 7 issue

Tags: 7, deployment, staging

I've installed and set up the deploy module; I've followed instruction on [Installation docs of deploy module for D7](http://drupal.org/node/1314318) and double checked it.

When I try to deploy node content, and run the cron, everything work great, the cron successfully ran, i also get "published message".

And there is nothing error. But, when i check my production site, the content that i've tried to deployed is not there. I've read http://drupal.org/node/1600862. Also i've installed latest dev entity_dependency module. And the content still not being deployed. Can anyone suggest?